# Dynamic URL in DataTable with golang

Tags: html, go, datatable

am trying of create dynamic URL in DataTable with golang

**The idea is to have some icons that remove an element from the table**

[Screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKCUW.png)

The columns are created in the controller by directly passing the link
all this after consulting the BDD
where the variable "id" concatenated in the string represents each element

```
cadenaS := "<a class='links' href='/history/search/" + id + "'><i class='fas fa-search' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>"

cadenaT := "<a class='links' href='/history/delete/" + id + "'><i class='far fa-trash-alt' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>"

his = append(his, History{ID: ID, Email: Email, Search: Search, Tipo: Tipo, Visited: Visited, Icon: &Icon{Search: cadenaS, Trash: cadenaT}})
```

To show it, the call is simply made with a response json

```
"columns": [
    {"data": "Icon.Search"},
    {"data": "Search"},
    {"data": "Visited"},
    {"data": "Icon.Trash"}
],
```

the URL that will receive the request to delete the item

```
http.HandleFunc("/history/delete/{id}", deleteHistory)
```

but never manages to make the call because the "ID" in the URL is not recognizing

Answer (score 2):

The standard `http` package does not allow URL variables. There are a few packages that do, for example [gorilla mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) is quite popular and can do that for you.